# Como Compactar arquivo no Upload? com ANGULAR

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, txt, arquivo-zip

Eu Preciso enviar uns arquivos para uma API, porém essa API só aceita arquivo .zip, e meu programa aceita que seja enviado .txt, porém quando for arquivo .txt, antes de enviar para API eu preciso pegar o arquivo txt e compactar ele para .zip

Eu precisava de alguma forma Nativa para fazer isso, pois na empresa estamos evitando usar bibliotecas para não dependermos de terceiros, alguém conhece alguma forma de fazer isso?

OBS: Projeto que estou trabalhando é uma versão WEB de um sistema desktop que já temos, no caso na versão desktop ele funciona dessa forma, e esse tratamento seria do lado servidor, o usuário pode sim fazer upload dos arquivos já zipado como também da versão TXT, porém se caso não for .zip o sistema precisa compactar antes de enviar para a API...

Comment: quer implementar essa lógica no lado cliente? ou criar no lado servidor?

Comment: se não quer depender de libs, deveria "obrigar" o usuário a fazer upload do arquivo já zipado. (seria uma responsabilidade do usuário).

Comment: Na verdade o Projeto que estou trabalhando é uma versão WEB de um sistema desktop que já temos, no caso na versão desktop ele funciona dessa forma, e respondendo a outra pergunta seria do lado servidor, o usuário pode sim fazer upload dos arquivos já zipado como também da versão TXT, porém  se caso não for .zip o sistema precisa compactar antes de enviar...

Comment: pois é cara, todas essas informações devem ser adicionadas ao corpo da pergunta, para deixar claro o problema. Poderia [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/578083/edit) a pergunta e adicionar as informações.

Comment: Nativamente somente implementado um algoritmo de escrita de arquivos especificados no documento [The .ZIP File Format](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) o padrão ECMA ainda não definiu suporte a arquivos ZIP. Uma alternativa seria importar uma biblioteca como [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) que dá suporte leitura e escrita de arquivos ZIP.

Comment: Seria possível no servidor criar um middleware entre o cliente e API, tal que receba a solicitação faça a compactação desse txt e só então passe a diante os dados para API no formato adequado?

Comment: @AugustoVasques, pensei nisso, mas no meu pensamento o `ap` possui uma espécie de BFF, então para mim ele faria esse middleware no lado servidor, no `bff`, antes de repassar a requisição para a outra API. Como ele não deseja utilizar lib de terceiros poderia fazer diretamente utilizando algum utilitário de linha de comando (pode ser até o do comando `zip`, que pode ser instalado via apt-get.

Comment: @Danizavtz é um cenário bastante plausível.

Comment: Olá, pensamos em fazer com a API, porém por se tratar de arquivos realmente grandes, fica inviável, pois eu teria que enviar, depois receber para depois então ter que enviar para outra API novamente, ou seja, o tempo de demora a partir do momento do meu click ENVIAR demoraria muito, então foi logo descartada.

Comment: A Maneira que encontramos para conseguir fazer foi utilizando a biblioteca PAKO, que já existia no nosso projeto, depois de quebrar muito a cabeça conseguimos, porém ele compacta no formato .gzip, ainda vou testar o envio para API, torcendo para que dê certo...

Comment: Eu achei uma possivel solução nativa mas ainda não testei pois a documentação diz não funcionar em Firefox e Safari. Em teoria seria possivel usar a API nativa de manipulação de streams de media e fazer um uso torto para zipar um arquivo texto. É uma gambiarra que poderia resolver o problema mas incorre em perda de compatibilidade com os navegadores citados e não é possível garantir que em atualizações dos navegadores compatíveis o algoritmo deflate(ZIP) esteja presente.